# process.uncaughtException not working in express

Tags: node.js, express

The code is very simple. You can check below,

app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(c);
    res.send('dddd')
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))

process.on('uncaughtException', (e)=>{  
    console.error('process error is:', e.message);  
    process.exit(1);
});
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e)=>{  
    console.error('unhandledRejection error is:', e.message);  
    process.exit(1);
});
```

When i run `node app.js` to start the server, and visit `http://localhost:3001/`, ReferenceError shows in the console and the process.uncaughtException function doesn't get executed. Can someone please help explain on this? thanks.

```js
$ node app.js
Example app listening at http://localhost:3001
ReferenceError: c is not defined
    at app.get (/Desktop/mine/test/app.js:7:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Desktop/mine/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What is `c` ? in console.log

Comment: The owner wrote that *undefined* variable in order to show you that the `uncaughtException` event is not fired whereas it should.

Answer (score 0):

remove `console.log(c)`. It is not defined.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('dddd')
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))

process.on('uncaughtException', (e)=>{  
    console.error('process error is:', e.message);  
    process.exit(1);
});
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e)=>{  
    console.error('unhandledRejection error is:', e.message);  
    process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wrote console.log(c) in order to let server throws exception to test process uncaughtException...